Addressing problem after automatic table update
Friends, I have a file that when opened, connects to a site and the table in the first sheet is automatically updated (once a day).
In the columns after this table, I wrote formulas that perform calculations according to the data in the table and output and return.
The problem is that when the length of the new day table is longer than the old table, it seems to be added between the lines. So that the addresses of the formula in the next cells of the table change.
For example, if the table is loaded in column A, and we write from the first cell to the 100th cell in column B:
=A1
=A2
.
.
.
=A100
and the current table should be 10 cells long (from A1:A10)
If we open the file tomorrow and the length of the new table is 20 (from A1:A20)
In column B, the formulas are correct only up to cell B10, but in cell B11, it is written =A21, while it should be written =A11
To solve this problem, should we use indirect addressing or is there a better solution?
I was able to solve this problem only through indirect addressing. But I am looking for a more correct way

if INDIRECT works, then what's not correct about it?  or are you still running into troubles?

I thought that in recent years, a more scientific solution has been designed for this problem!

Is the data loaded into an Excel Table? If so, you can reference the entire column in the table using the tableName[columnName] syntax in the formula. What version of Excel are you running? (ie do you have the UNIQUE function available as a test).

Excel 365
I need to calculate each cell of the table separately. Now it works with the =INDIRECT("B" & ROW()) command, but I think there is a more scientific way. There is no need to replace any address in the formula. , wrote this long string

I think we need more detail on "the first sheet is automatically updated". How does this happen? A VBA macro, or PowerQuery? You certainly want to avoid using INDIRECT if you can.

I don't really get the problem, but instead of INDIECT, have you considered non-volatile =index(b:b,row()) ? But depending on what calculation you need to perform, you may not need it at all. Also if you have Excel 365, why tag Excel 2007?

If your data is in a table as are your formulas, then as @DS_London mentioned, you can use '@cell' addressing in your formulas.  To add to that though, select a cell in your table then go to Data > Properties. Then tick "Preserve column sort/filter/layout". This combination should help.

Thank you friends. But why did you tag Excel 2007 considering that you are using Excel 365?
Because when we want to send a post, the Tag Law site has at least 5 forums. And when we search Excel, the number of related forums is not many. I think there are 6 in total.
